# How can I use media queries to move Bootstrap menu options to a separate 'more options' menu when the screen width is too low to display all options?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am using Bootstrap 3 to develop a website and I know that on the standard templates there is a full menu and then a mobile menu depending on screen width, however, I would like to implement something in between these two that moves some of the options to a 'more' menu before showing the mobile menu bar. I have put together a diagram below to better explain what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Say your in between size is the small screen (768-992px).

Using media queries or visible-sm classes you can have a "more" link show only for small devices with `visible-sm`. Take the "blog" and "testimonials" tabs and apply the `hidden-sm` classes to those.